# blackberry: how can i make sure not to upload a file already present on server

Tags: file, blackberry, upload

My question is that how I can make sure that I don't upload any file I already have on the server on blackberry.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in blackberry or php any one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to check that in serverside. if the file is not there, then it will upload or else it will show alert message.

for PHP you can use below Code.

```
  <?php   
    if (file_exists("http://www.example.com/abc.jpg"))  
        echo "File Exists";  // Upload the file
    else   
        echo "File does not Exists";  //show Alert Message
    ?>
```